# Is it true that $\int t\frac{dF}{d \ln{t}} d \ln{t}=\int \frac{dF}{dt} dt$

Tags: calculus, integration, logarithms, exponential-function

It seems to be true that:

$$\int t\frac{dF}{d \ln{t}} d \ln{t}=\int \frac{dF}{dt} dt$$

For eg., this works with $\frac{dF}{dt}=\frac{1}{2} (\cos(\pi \ln{t})+1)$

But then there must be something wrong because this would imply that $\int t dF=\int dF$ which seems unlikely.

I would appreciate it if someone could demonstrate why the first displayed equation is correct or incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

A counter-example to the above formula is $F(t) = \ln t$. Then
$$
\int t \frac{d F}{d \ln t} d(\ln t) = \int dt = t,
$$
but
$$
\int \frac{dF}{dt}dt = \int \frac{1}{t}dt = \ln t.
$$

You can perform the u-substitution $u = \ln t$ to see that that
$$
\int t \frac{d F}{d \ln t} d(\ln t)
$$